# Getting payment gateway script form controller and displaying on view but payment button is not displaying

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am using CodeIgniter. I have a script which comes from the controller and displaying on view page using AJAX and JSON.

Basically below code is the payment gateway code.

First time I am integrating the payment gateway. I have zero knowledge in integrating the gateway. I am trying using documentation.

Please help me with the best solution.

I am using below code. If I add below code directly on view page then it's working but If I get this code from controller then it's not working. I mean I am not getting the `proceed to payment` button.

If I add this code directly on view page then I am getting the payment gateway popup.

**Why I added below code in the controller**

Because I have some HTML and PHP code in the controller and I am displaying that code using AJAX and JSON. So I thought, I can add payment gateway code to the controller and get it by JSON.

**controller**

```
$paymentAPI="**************";
$Paymentrequirement .= ' 
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div><h2>INR <span id="totalDetails"></span></h2></div>
  </div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
         <form action="/purchase" method="POST">
         <!--Note that the amount is in paise = 50 INR -->
        <script
            src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
            data-key="'.$paymentAPI.'"
            data-amount="100"
            data-buttontext="proceed to payment"
            data-name="test"
            data-description="Purchase Description"
            data-image="logo"
            data-prefill.name="'.$getLoginMemberDetails->first_name.'' .$getLoginMemberDetails->last_name.'"
            data-prefill.email="'.$getLoginMemberDetails->email.'"
            data-theme.color="#F37254"
        ></script>
        <input type="hidden" value="Hidden Element" name="hidden">

        </form>

  </div>

</div>';
 echo json_encode($Paymentrequirement);
 exit();
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Member_controller/ProcessSection",
       // context: document.body,
       dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
          $('#ProcessModel').html(data);
        }});
});
```

Comment: you said that clicking on "proceed to payment" button redirects you to /purchase URL. I am assuming that it happens after you ajax call appends the form to #ProcessModel. I would suggest you to check the type of "proceed to payment" button type or share its code here.

Comment: @umair.ashfr, Thanks for the response,  I haven't use any code for the button. Gateway providing a button which is data-buttontext="proceed to payment" and

Comment: @umair.ashfr, I updated my question and description. I am not getting the payment button from the controller on the view page.